# How to check if a number is constructed of letters only

Tags: assembly

I was wondering how to determine if a number is constructed entirely of letters.
For example, the number `AAAA` / `BBBB` / `FABE` and so on, are numbers which consist letters only.
On the other hand, the number `ABC6` has a number in it, therefore, it's not a letter number.

Comment: You'll have to add some more detailed context, for example in what form is the input given? What kind of CPU/assembler? What's the desired output?

Comment: And for what purpose - making "words" such as `BEEF`? If so, should `0` and `1` be included which can be used for `O` and `I`?

Comment: Try this = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326386/assembly-32bit-how-to-check-a-string/30328393#30328393

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if the digital number that is stored in some register consists of letters only when you convert the number to hexadecimal? Right?

This is the same question as: ... if the hexadecimal representation contains only digits >= N while N is 0xA in your case.

If leading zeros are also not allowed (in this case you have to specify the number of hexadecimal digits!) a would suggest the following algorithm:

Mask out the "even" positions of the hexadecimal number and subtract 0xA from each position. Then check if there is a carry/borrow into the "odd" positions.

Do the same for the "odd" positions of the number. If you use the full width of the number (such as 8 digits for a 32-bit number) you also have to check the carry-out from the upper digit!

In x86 assembly this algorithm would look like this for 8-digit hexadecimal numbers:

```
mov EAX, number_to_be_tested
and EAX, 0xF0F0F0F ; Mask even digits
sub EAX, 0xA0A0A0A ; Subtract 0xA from even digits
test EAX, 0xF0F0F0F0 ; Check for a carry/borrow into an odd digit
jnz contains_numbers
mov EAX, number_to_be_tested
and EDX, 0xF0F0F0F0 ; Do the same with teh odd digits...
sub EAX, 0xA0A0A0A0
jc contains_numbers ; Special case: The uppermost digit...
test EAX, 0xF0F0F00
jnz contains_numbers
jmp contains_letters_only
```

If you want to allow leading zeros (such as 0x000ABCDE = 0xABCDE) you'll have to modify this algorithm a bit...

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way I wrote on my knee. I'm not saying it's the best.

```
; AX = the number
mov dx, ax
and ax, 0x8888
xor ax, 0x8888
jnz .nope

test dx, 0x0006
jz .nope
test dx, 0x0060
jz .nope
test dx, 0x0600
jz .nope
test dx, dx
jz .nope

jmp .yep

.nope:
```